# Regarding the immortality of the gods in Immortals (2011)?

Tags: plot-explanation, immortals

In the film [Immortals](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1253864/), Zeus and the other Gods descend from Mount Olympus to battle the Titans. Seeing that the following facts should be known about the Gods

- Zeus: God of the Sky, Thunder and Lightning
- Poseidon: God of the seas
- Heracles (demi-god? need confirmation on this)
- Athena: Goddess of warfare
- Apollo: God of healing

How is it possible for the Gods to die so quickly? Without placing the emphasis on mythology and on the script alone, it is at least known that Poseidon has the power of the sea right? Even in the ending scene where Phaedra's son foresees Theseus and the Gods in battle with the Titans, we see only one on one battles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only reasonable explanation I can think of is that the Gods portrayed here are more 'mortal' than what we are used to thinking of.  The battle that was alluded to in the beginning of the movie sounded like the God/Titan battle was more evenly matched than the 'canon' Greek mythology.

Honestly, I consider this movie more an adaptation of Greek mythology than what is accepted based on the anonymity of the Titans.  The Titans themselves seem to be all the same, no distinction between any of them.  After all, where is Chronus, Atlus, Gaia, etc?

That being said, the reason that the 'immortal' Gods are so easily killed is because of that even matching of the Titans strength + numbers against the Gods.